# Raspberry Pi: Error when using Kivy's TextInput(): [CRITICAL] [Clipboard ] Unable to find any valuable Clipboard provider at all

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote a dmx control program in python using kivy.
I tried to copy it onto a raspberry pi 2 version b (with raspberian installed on it, python and kivy as described in the manual of kivy->manual installation on a raspberry pi.)

Everything works fine, i only get an error, when a TextInput() is displayed on the widget currently loaded. I got these errors:

[image: Error]

On my computer running windows 7 x64 everything is going fine.

Following I tried to solve the problem:

- I changed all "TextInput" into "Label" widgets, everything worked. So it must be the TextInput
- I connected a USB keyboard on the raspberry pi to check, if the error has something to do with missing key input devices - there is no change with oder without keyboard.

Here is the contents of the kivy config.ini file:

```
[kivy]
keyboard_repeat_delay = 300
keyboard_repeat_rate = 30
log_dir = logs
log_enable = 1
log_level = info
log_name = kivy_%y-%m-%d_%_.txt
window_icon =
keyboard_mode =
keyboard_layout = qwerty
desktop = 1
exit_on_escape = 0
pause_on_minimize = 0
config_version = 14

[graphics]
display = -1
fullscreen = 0
height = 600
left = 0
maxfps = 60
multisamples = 2
position = auto
rotation = 0
show_cursor = 1
top = 0
width = 800
resizable = 1
borderless = 0
window_state = visible
minimum_width = 0
minimum_height = 0

[input]
mouse = mouse
%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput,param=invert_y=0

[postproc]
double_tap_distance = 20
double_tap_time = 250
ignore = []
jitter_distance = 0
jitter_ignore_devices = mouse,mactouch,
retain_distance = 50
retain_time = 0
triple_tap_distance = 20
triple_tap_time = 375

[widgets]
scroll_timeout = 250
scroll_distance = 20
scroll_friction = 1.
scroll_stoptime = 300
scroll_moves = 5

[modules]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip xsel
```